# How to design a web UI using ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Using a lightweight framework such as Sinatra, how is the best way to present information and receive information from a user that is simple to code for, yet pleasing to the eye.

Frontend design is not my strong suit so I am searching for options that will allow me to get right to the point of displaying information to the user and allowing the user fire off work requests to the backend. **This should also have mobile browser support.**

For example, on the main page I would like to list the status of some machine with two buttons to start and stop work:

```
System powered:      On
System status:       Idle
Workload present:    True
Last work activated: Today

[Start Work]  [Pause Work]
```

But I would like to have some easy on the eyes formatting, UI design, and colorization that wont make users gouge their eyes out.

More or less I am wanting to output textual information to the user and accept button presses to fire events off in the backend without having to dig through documentation of bootstrap frameworks for days or learn the intricacies of CSS, HTML5, and javascript.

Thanks.

Comment: IMHO using a CSS Framework like Bootstrap, Bulma, Foundation, etc is probably the fastest and easiest way to build such a simple page when you do not know enough HTML and CSS to build it by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest adding front end related tags like `html` `css` and `javascript` and `ui design`. This is so people who have a keen interest in those technologies (web UI design) can chip in and give you some suggestions/ answers.

Secondly, this questions seems quite broad. In the beginning you asked about presenting and receiving information and then later your have an example of just the front-end.

Here is my answer anyway:

https://jsfiddle.net/tgcmkf0p/6/